# Help critique my analysis proof of convergence.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on my proof for convergence that the sequence $\frac{3n +2}{2n + 1}$ converges to $\frac{3}{2}$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given and choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so large that $N > \frac{1}{4\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2}$. By the archimedean property $n > N$ then $n > \frac{1}{4\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2}$. This leads to $\frac{1}{4n +2} < \epsilon$ and since $|\frac{3n +2}{2n + 1} - \frac{3}{2}| = |\frac{1}{4n + 2}|$ we can conclude that $|\frac{3n +2}{2n + 1} - \frac{3}{2}| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Looks pretty finished.

Comment: I caught one thing, epsilon should be arbitrary not given.

Comment: In my understanding, "given" means "given arbitrarily". But explicitly having an "arbitrary" in the prose doesn't hurt.

Comment: Agree with @DanielFischer, the proof is good as it stands. Using "given" here is perfectly correct. $\epsilon$ has to be given before $N=N_{\epsilon}$ can be found. This is totally standard in every way.